# Retaining dropdown selection on page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select, url-parameters

I have a select list on a page like this:

```
<select name='elements'>
    <option value='water'>Water</option>
    <option value='fire'>Fire</option>
    <option value='air'>Air</option>
</select>
```

**EDIT**: When a user makes a selection, the current page is refreshed, but how do I keep the user's selection visible in the list after the page refresh? In other words, I don't want the list to rollback to its default selected value.

Help please

Comment: Is there any reason you want a full page refresh? why not simply show/hide/populate from an async call...?

Comment: I wanna translate the content of the whole page into another language, so yes I want a full page refresh

Answer (score 4):

Here is a Javascript-only solution.

```
 <select name='elements' id='elements' onChange='window.location="yoururl.html?value=" + this.value;'>
     <option value='water'>Water</option>
     <option value='fire'>Fire</option>
     <option value='air'>Air</option>
 </select>
```

Then you use [this](http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html) function to see if the `value` parameter is set and get it and you can use jQuery to set it as `selected`.

```
$("#elements option[value='" + result_of_gup + "']").attr("selected","selected") ;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 <select name='elements' onChange='window.location="yoururl.php?value=" + this.value;'>
     <option value='water'>Water</option>
     <option value='fire'>Fire</option>
     <option value='air'>Air</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: What about the `keeping the user's selection visible in the list`?

Comment: You have to worry about that on the `yoururl.php?value=fire` page, as long as you have a new page load with the querystring, just use that value to render your new page accordingly.. To preselect an item in a list just do `<option value="" selected></option>`. Also, you barely posted any code, so its hard to say what you're truly needing accomplished.

Answer (score 0):

Doing it without jQuery:

Create `window.location.getParameter()` function (see **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript/8812157#8812157)** from **[Anatoly Mironov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/632117/anatoly-mironov)**) then:

```
<select name='elements' id='elements' onChange='window.location="yoururl.html?elements=" + this.selectedIndex;'>
   <option value='water'>Water</option>
   <option value='fire'>Fire</option>
   <option value='air'>Air</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
  els = document.getElementById('elements');
  selIndex = window.location.getParameter('elements') || 0;
  els[selIndex].selected = true;​
</script>
```

For ease of reference, I reproduce Anatoly's excellent `.getParameter` function below:

```
window.location.getParameter = function(key) {
    function parseParams() {
        var params = {},
            e,
            a = /\+/g,  // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
            r = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
            d = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(a, " ")); },
            q = window.location.search.substring(1);

        while (e = r.exec(q))
            params[d(e[1])] = d(e[2]);

        return params;
    }

    if (!this.queryStringParams)
        this.queryStringParams = parseParams(); 

    return this.queryStringParams[key];
};
```